# Match pairs of nodes with reciprocal relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a data model where nodes of the same label are connected by relationships of the same type:

[image]

There is no hierarchy or 'logic' which of the `:Concept` nodes is the start node of the reciprocal relationship.

My goal is to get all unique pairs of nodes. Wen you match on the `:Concept` nodes, you get two pairs, one starting at `123` the other starting at `234`:

```
MATCH (c1:Concept)-[:REL]->(c2:Concept)
RETURN [c1.concept_id, c2.concept_id]
```

Result:

```
[123, 234]
[234, 123]
```

Is there a way to get each pair only once? The order of the pairs does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
MATCH (c1:Concept)-[:REL]-(c2:Concept)
WHERE id(c1) > id(c2)
RETURN [c1.concept_id, c2.concept_id]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy ;)